Automatically Delete or Deactivate Process Builder from a 1st-Gen Managed Released Package after migrating it to Flows
I'm migrating some record triggered Process Builder process to Flows, and I'm not being able to remove, or at least deactivate the old PBs from the 1st-Gen Managed Released Package, and as result, after the subscriber updates to this new version, all these automations run twice when records are created, once from the PB, and once again from the Flows, causing duplicated results.
What I've tried so far:

Deactivating the current PB version: that doesn't deactivate when the subscriber updates;
Adding a new inactive PB version and deactivating the previous: it is installed as inactive but doesn't deactivate the previous on the subscriber;
Contacting support to enable PB versions deletion, and deleting the old versions keeping only the last one as inactive: previous versions still keep active on the subscriber side.
Adding a PostInstall Apex script and calling out the tooling API to deactivate the PBs in an async transaction: doesn't work because there is no valid SessionId to authenticate.

So, my question is, is there a way to automatically (with no action from the subscriber side) delete, or stop these flows from being triggered, on the package update scenario?
For now, my workaround is to create a new Active “empty/dummy” PB version, so although it’s still triggered, it does nothing, and works for both a clean install and for updates, but that doesn't seem the ideal approach.
Note: I did research about it, including other similar stack exchange questions, but most are not working (for my use case) and old stuff, and now since PB retirement is coming soon, things could have changed a bit.
Appreciate any help,
Thank you.
